# Expandable content in the drupal node page (Javascript functionality)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, teaser

I need to display a trimmed version of the content on the node page and upon clicking on a link ("Read More"), the page should expand ? Is there any Drupal Module that implements this functionality ? [image: Please see the attached Image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a Drupal module to wrap it, but you can easily do that using a jQuery plugin like [readmore](http://rockycode.com/blog/jquery-plugin-readmore/) in the node view template.

It's a simple as doing

```
$(foo).readmore();
```